# Display special characters on input placeholder with CakePHP form helper

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, form-helpers

I need to display a special character in the placeholder for my input.

Any suggestions?

```
echo $this->Form->control('inputName',
    [
        'placeholder' => '&#8467;'
    ]
);
```

Output:

```
<input name='inputName' placeholder='&#8467;'>
```

Answer (score 5):

you can also set escape to false this way:

```
echo $this->Form->control('inputName',
    [
        'placeholder' => '&#8467;',
        'escape' => false
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can HTML decode the encoded entity to pass it correctly.

```
echo $this->Form->control('inputName',
    [
        'placeholder' => html_entity_decode('&#8467;')
    ]
);
```

Output:

```
<input name="inputName" placeholder="ℓ">
```